# Select a JSON field key on an Adonis Lucid subquery

Tags: javascript, postgresql, activerecord, adonis.js

I have two simple lucid models, called `Parent` (table parents) and `Child` (table children). The children table has a JSON field we call `jsoncolumn`.

My parent model has a belongsToMany relationship to the model Child.

```
children() {
    return this.belongsToMany('App/Models/Child').pivotTable('parent_child');
}
```

From various parents, I want to fetch the value of the parent, plus the value contained within the field `jsoncolumn`, at the key `key`; for that I want to use the PostgreSQL operator `->`. Using Adonis Lucid syntax, it gives the following code:

```
Parent.query().select('*')
    .with('children', builder => {
        builder.select(Database.raw("jsoncolumn->'key' AS foo"));
    }).fetch();
```

Problem, the following code does not work. Even if within a `Database.raw` clause, the operator is quoted... so the generated select is:

> SELECT "children"."jsoncolumn->'key'"

Note that it does not allow as well to use any function. Anything that is not a column name, actually, will not work.

What would be the correct syntax in order to do that?

Answer (score 2):

To make a query to `JSON` data type at MySQL Server you need to do in the following way

```
SELECT columnOne, jsonColumn->'$.key' as Data FROM TableName;
```

I mean you have an incorrect sintax since you dont use the `$.` sign before the `builder.select(Database.raw("jsoncolumn->'$.key' AS foo"));`

Why?

The short sintax you're using requires it as my previous exaples shows to you